# Can I use the iPhone 4's camera via my Mac?

Tags: iphone, mac, video, webcam

I'd like to record some video on my MacBook Pro, which I could do using the built-in iSight except I'd like to record in HD. Rather than go out and buy a new HD video camera, is there any way of getting the Mac to recognise the iPhone 4's HD camera as an input?

Yes I know that I could just use the iPhone on its own and then transfer the video over, but I'd like to be able to see what I'm recording (without using mirrors). Have done a bit of Googling and can't see anything, so just thought I'd ask!

Answer (score 1):

I've tried this, but unfortunately it doesn't work with iChat and PhotoBooth but works perfectly with Skype and other communications tools :

[iWebcamera iPhone App ($4.99)](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/iwebcamera/id369617568?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D6#)

Comment: Is it HD though?

Comment: Is there alternative apps that can doesn't have restrictions?